# Saturation voltage of diode connected mosfet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I am trying to build and simulate current mirror using discrete components.

Below picture shows circuit configuration in OrCad for simulating in PSPICE.

[image]

The problem is that the large signal voltage at the drain stays around 3.1V(3.146V shown above), and I can only control using voltages from 3.1V~4.3V. 
I tried changing R3 from 100Ohm to 2K Ohm, but it doesn't seem to affect that voltage significantly. I checked datasheet, and Rds On is 13Ohms in saturation, so the transistor doesn't seem to be in saturation. Is there any way I can lower that voltage?

Comment: *so the transistor doesn't seem to be in saturation* As it is connected as a diode, it **cannot** even be in saturation mode.

Comment: You should really study: 1) how a current mirror actually works 2) what the characteristics of MOSFETs are. From your question I conclude that you're just "doing something", don't understand it and this is getting you nowhere. You mention Rdson, which is **irrelevant** in a current mirror. And although this circuit could "work" in a simulator, it is not going to work very well in practice. Discrete NMOS like 2n7002 have a very large W/L and therefore Ids is extremely sensitive to Vgs.

Comment: With drain and gate connected together, Vds is constraint by Vgs, not much you can do. You can try to find a MOSFET with lower Vgs/Vth (or use BJT). Beware of variability as mentioned by FakeMoustache. By the way, you are applying BJT terminology to MOSFET and that is confusing. For example, saturation in MOSFET behaves almost like the opposite of saturation in BJT.